# SequelizeJS: Migration failing when starting from scratch

Tags: sequelize.js

I wonder if the way I am implementing my app/migrations is wrong. On app start, I run `MODEL_NAME.sync()` on each model. This is to create the table if it does not exist. The problem is when want to setup my app on a clean DB, migrations will fail as it detects that columns etc already exist. How should I resolve this?

Comment: I think this is an issue with sequelize, it should ignore the addColumn in the migration if the column already exists. Instead it fails.

Comment: Actually, `MODEL_NAME.sync()` is better to avoid altogether. It's better to, in stead, use the `umzug` framework to run the migrations. This also allows for better configuration.